# How can i solve this error named Route [delete-blog] not defined in my blade file?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, defined

I have route name named delete-blog but i got error named Route Not Defined.
I ran route:clear , cache:clear , config:cache and view:clear but that didn't work.
I changed route name but i got this error again.

how can i solve this problem ?
Can you help me?

My route code :

```
Route::get('haber/sil/{id}', 'BlogDeleteController')->middleware('auth.custom')->name('delete-blog');
```

Comment: put your function name in the route definition. `Route::get('haber/sil/{id}', 'BlogDeleteController@delete_blog')->middleware('auth.custom')->name('delete-blog');`

Comment: Could you add blog.blade.php code source ?

Comment: ``` 
<li>
                                                    <a href="{{route('delete-blog',$blog->id)}}">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle">&nbsp;</i>
                                                        <div class="texting"><span>Gönderiyi Kaldır</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect not to have function name in your route if you are not using `resource` Route but if you got `Route not defined` that is not the reason, otherwise you get `Method not defined error`.

Check if you have your Route in route group where you have `'as' => '[something]...'` parameter.

Whatever reason it should be you must put function name in your route declaration:

```
 Route::get('haber/sil/{id}', 'BlogDeleteController@[Your delete Method Name Here]')->middleware('auth.custom')->name('delete-blog'); //put your function name
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friend for your help.
I solved this problem , like that :

My old route :

```
Route::get('haber/sil/{id}', 'BlogDeleteController')->middleware('auth.custom')->name('delete-blog');
```

My new route

```
Route::get('news/destroy/{id}', 'BlogDeleteController')->middleware('auth.custom')->name('delete-blog');
```

Comment: Should be like this  Route::delete('news/{id}', 'BlogDeleteController@destroy');

Comment: I know , i develop this project. other programmers did BlogDeleteController .

Actualy this must be NewsController . I will solve this problem .